# iOS game crashes after pressing "Share" button only on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, crash

My iOS game crashes after the share button is pressed. This button then gives the users the option to post to Twitter, FB, Mail, Messages,etc. I am able to replicate the crash on the iPad simulator running iOS 8.2.

The crash report can be found at: 
http://a4.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple3/v4/bf/b4/c1/bfb4c1cb-1662-7df2-685b-633f2f0695f5/temp..lkqrtgbn.crash?downloadKey3=1430556453_c5495376ad47fae8a489d4b504b91730

Any thoughts to what might be causing the crash or how to remedy the situation?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report. Once you do that, update your question with the symbolicated stack trace for thread 0 (the thread that crashed).

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS game crashes after pressing Share button only on iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997369/ios-game-crashes-after-pressing-share-button-only-on-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load some library when share button is pressed? If YES, I'm afraid that your library don't have support on Simulator. (i368 architecture)

Comment: The app was rejected by Apple due to the crash. I have not personally been able to test on an iPad but I assume Apple did.